# replacing ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

The fixture has three white wires tied together and one black.  The new fan has a black, blue, white, and green.  B[image: lack and blue wired to three whites, and the white to the black from the fixture? Green is ground, but no ground. Or are the three whites all neutral?[![enter i]mage description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcFwF.jpg)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EcFwF.jpg)
Success!  Thanks everyone!

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos of the fixture box and any switch boxes involved?

Comment: On the new fan Black is the hot for the fan motor, Blue is hot for the light(s), White is neutral, and Green is ground.  I would have to assume that the three white wires are neutral, but without examining the wiring, it's impossible to say for sure.

Comment: By "fixture" do you mean the ceiling box? Are these wires "Romex" or are they individual wires in conduit? Three white wires connected together *and* one black sounds strange. I would expect the number of black to equal the number of white wires. Is there a wall switch that controls the power to this box?

Comment: Yes, ceiling box. Wall switch controls it. Power to ceiling box then to switch? I have a photo, not sure how to post

Comment: @Davidwcats51 Can you also post a picture of the switch on the wall (rather, *behind* the switch so we can see the wires)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is a switch loop setup

What we see here is an old-style switch loop.  While the three white wires you see bundled together at the fan box are indeed neutral, the white wire from the switch isn't one of them -- it instead gets bundled in with the always-hot wires in the fan box to provide power to the switch.  The black wire from the switch then carries power back to become the black wire going to the fan.

So, presuming you've checked to make sure the box can take the load:

- Wire white on the fan to the bundle of white wires.
- Wire black and blue on the fan to the lone black wire.
- Nut off the grounds on the fan
- Button it all up and turn the power back on
- Enjoy your new fan

Answer (score -2):

**Disclaimer: You should never attempt to do any electrical work on your own always call a licensed electrical contractor, if you are going to do it yourself always make sure to turn off the power before doing anything**

Your old fan or light was controlled off of a single switch (judging from pictures) but the new one is set up so you can have separate switches on the wall for both the light and the fan.

Assuming you don't want to go through the effort of ripping open your walls and running new lines to add a separate switch in so you can control the light and fan off of separate switches the following was how you should connect your wires:

First connect the green wire to the back of the box as it is your ground, then Connect the white wire to your neutral connection (the twisted white wires), then twist your blue and black wires together and connect them to your hot wire (black in ceiling).